# Firefox 6 background image repeat issue

Tags: firefox, background

I realize that the title is a long one, but allow me to explain. If you look at:

http://hardincountychamber.org/Chamber-Commerce-Directory.asp

in Firefox 6 (Windows 7 64bit), the white background will repeat until around halfway through the letter 'D' of the full directory, and then disappear after one small move of the mouse wheel, and then resume displaying just a little further down the page. The background just snaps back to displaying. Personally I am baffled as to what is causing it, and in the back-end admin section of this page, the same thing occurs with another repeated background image.

So to duplicate the bug, at the time of this postings, search for the term, "Starbuck" on the page, and then scroll until that listing is at top of your browser, then scroll down slowly, and the white background should just disappear.

Any help would be extremely helpful, though I am going to have to paginate the results of this page for a quick fix, I would rather know what it is that is causing it, and maybe even a potential fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check, that happens when you scroll the page down by slightly more than 32000 pixels (yep, signed 16-bit integer limit). Things are even worse in Firefox 9, there the background doesn't come back below that boundary. Which sounds pretty close to [bug 215055](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215055) - except that it cannot be that bug, it has been resolved two years ago. There doesn't seem to be an existing report for the bug you found, it is probably best if you [file a new bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core), component is "Layout".

Comment: I have submitted a new bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685174

Thank you for your help, and your suggestion. I just wanted to make sure that there wasn't some simple fix.